# How come optical data modulation is faster than that of electrical modulation while optical modulation is done by electricity?

Tags: modulation, optical-fibre, optical

why optical data is of high bandwidth that that of electrical copper data bandwidth when we use electrical signal to achieve optical data modulation ?

Comment: you can transmit multiple colors and use optical filters at the receiver to separate the signals .... each of the signals could be running at maximum copper data bandwidth

Comment: yes but copper too can transmit data at different frequencies like optical colors (different frequencies ) and separate different frequencies at the receiver. so, that highlight the question ( for a small length say 1 meter between say two computer nodes which type of communication regarding the high bandwidth and data speed and density excluding cost and optical fibers length advantages.

Comment: you're ignoring the fact that the different frequencies that e.g. a coax cable can carry are limited, e.g. your average consumer-grade transmission line will cut off at some GHz. So, let's say your electrically usable bandwidth is 1 GHz. In optics, you're doing the same - conducting an electromagnetic wave in a waveguide – but you're doing it potentially with 10s of GHzes of bandwidth.

Answer (score 4):

The problem here is not the feasibility of the modulation, but the ability for cables to carry high speed signals.

Especially with long length, it is much easier (and economical) to carry a high speed signal on en optical fiber than on an electric cable.

Comment: yes, but exclude the length ( suppose the fiber-optic and copper cable are connecting two nodes of one meter apart ) which will provide the highest-bandwidth of data transmission and why?

Comment: For very fast signals, even 1 meter is long and provide significant attenuation. You may achieve a high speed transmission by sending a high power signal on one end and receive a low-power signal on the other end. But nobody would do this, since optical fiber will be less expensive and less power-hungry.

Comment: attenuation isn't even the main problem. The main problem is that if you send a signal that covers e.g. 1 to 1000 MHz, then that signal will have about twice the bandwidth of its center frequency, and thus, the cable will have very different delays for the low and the high frequencies within that band. That means that you try to send 999 Mbaud, but since every symbol you send contains *all* the frequencies, the low frequencies of the next symbol "overtake" the high frequencies of the previous one – you get inter-symbol interference, and a mishmash on the output that you can't pick apart.

Comment: now, if you now send the same 999 MHz bandwidth on an optical carrier frequency (some hundred Terahertz), the bandwidth is a tiny fraction of the center frequency – and the frequency-selective effects on the medium don't really matter. Hence, typically, high bandwidth gets easier the higher your carrier frequency becomes.

Comment: @dellpc, if you exclude length, then optics has no advantage. For the very shortest distances (one side of a chip to another) we almost always still use electrical signals. Even at distances of 1 or 2 meters, there are very few systems that use optics rather than electrical signals. It's only for long distances that optics win.

Comment: @MarcusMüller, and yet in a fiber optic transceiver, for example, you still have to deliver, for example, 100 Gbps from host connector to the laser, over a distance of a few cm. And such things can be done.

Comment: @ThePhoton sure! But: a) if "short" means "shorter than a wavelength", things are relatively benign as long as you can match lengths and impedances, b) well, even local buses that are serial and high speed need some form of link training/equalization, which is a lot of hassle.

Comment: (and c) it's not that a 24 Gbps optical link wouldn't have some form of equalizer, probably, but let's not complicate things or do something like weakening my argument...)

Comment: @MarcusMüller, OK, but specifically to your comment about "999 Mbaud", IIRC in the days of 1 gigabit Ethernet, we used to specify up to 18" (~50 cm) trace length between a PHY chip and an optical transceiver. So for short distance (3-4 wavelengths, here) the situation isn't as dire as you said, even in microstrip trace (which is much more dispersive than coax). In coax or twisted pair we can run 1 Gbps for 10's of meters at lower cost than using fiber. (Yes you use multiple pairs, but it's still lower cost than a single fiber with laser and receiver).